# Spring Roo pizza shop pizza order

Tags: spring-roo

I am new to 'Spring Roo' and I am going through the [Pizza Shop](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html) example.

I was able to run it but there is no way to add multiple pizzas of same type in one order, i.e. you can add multiple pizzas of different types, but not of same type. How can this be achieved, through 'Roo'?

Also, if i were to add it manually, how am i supposed to store it:

```
Map<Pizza,Integer>
```

Pizza - the actual ordered pizza

Integer - number of Pizzas?

Comment: Makes sense to me that you'd use a Map to do that.  Not sure you can do it with Roo commands, but you can always just change things around in the Order.java file, annotated it with Hibernate/JPA annotations.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a join table (e.g. Order Line Item) as shown in this class diagram: [image: join table]

This instance diagram shows an example of the records in the database after a customer has placed an order for 3 pizzas: 2x Pepperoni and 1x Neapolitan: [image]

Here is an example (from a different domain) of using a join table in roo: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286833/how-to-do-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-spring-roo-with-attributes-within-de-r)

Comment: I think I was doing it all wrong. Maybe I should create a separate object with fields: Order, Item and Quantity. Use an List to hold all order items. In case where each item has to be separately identified, eg. in case of electronics(serial id), etc. your technique will be needed.