# many to many relationship with sorting

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many, persistence, spring-roo

i am trying to achieve a MANY_TO_MANY relationship between two entities with an additional attribute in the join table.
i found the following answer:
[how-to-do-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-spring-roo-with-attributes-within-de-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286833/how-to-do-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-spring-roo-with-attributes-within-de-r/7385463#7385463)
but i failed trying to adapt the offered solution to my scenario:

currently i have a straight forward MANY_TO_MANY relationship:

```
 # book:
 entity jpa --class ~.domain.Book --testAutomatically
 field string --fieldName title --notNull
 field string --fieldName subtitle --notNull
 field string --fieldName description
 # n:m relationship to author
 field list --fieldName authors --type ~.domain.Author --cardinality MANY_TO_MANY

 # author:
 entity jpa --class ~.domain.Author --testAutomatically
 field string --fieldName firstName --notNull
 field string --fieldName lastName --notNull
```

that works as expected, but i need to have the authors ordered. i would like to achieve this by defining the relationship table and adding a integer field like 'sequence' to it, but i got stuck when i try to define the many-to-many relationship in Book:

```
 entity jpa --class ~.domain.BookAuthorOrdered  --table book_author_ordered
 # the additional field to store sequence of authors:
 field number --fieldName authorSequence --type java.lang.Integer --notNull
 # reference to book:
 field reference --fieldName bookId --type ~.domain.Book --cardinality MANY_TO_ONE 

 # reference to author:
 field reference --fieldName authorId --type ~.domain.Author --cardinality MANY_TO_ONE
```

can anyone give me a hint how to define the attribute in Book so that i get a list of sorted authors using the above defined join table? here is something i tried:

```
 # complete the relationship
 focus --class ~.domain.Book
 field list --type ~.domain.BookAuthorOrdered --fieldName orderedAuthors --cardinality ONE_TO_MANY --mappedBy bookId
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the [@OrderBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html) annotation to entity field (in *.java* file). By example:

```
   @ManyToMany
   @OrderBy("lastName ASC, firstName ASC")
   private List<Author> authors;
```

Comment: hi @jmvivo, thanks for that hint, but this would not solve my problem. i need an order in the associated authors for a book. like first author, second author,... so i need an additional column in the join table to sort the author associations to the book.

Comment: Try to use authors @Id property, this should be enough (some like `@OrderBy("authId ASC")` ).

Comment: maybe i understand you wrong, but as i mentioned before i do not need a sorting of the authors by `id` or any other attribute (like `firstName`) of the `author` table itself. what i really need is a sorting of the **n:m** (book <=> author) association. on database level i can reach that aim by adding a "sorting attribute" `authorSequence` to the **join table** `BookAuthorOrdered`. i described this in the solution i posted on Aug 14. this works for me but it does not look elegant at all to me.

Answer (score 0):

i found a more or less working solution for my problem, but it still has some drawbacks. it is mostly derived from the above mentioned answer:
[How to do a many-to-many relationship in spring Roo, with attributes within de relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286833/how-to-do-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-spring-roo-with-attributes-within-de-r/7385463#7385463)

create join table manually with ids of the tables book and author as composed primary key:
    roo> entity jpa --class ~.domain.BookAuthorOrdered  --table book_author_ordered --identifierType ~.domain.BookAuthorOrderedId
    field number --fieldName authorSequence --type java.lang.Integer --notNull

then edit the generated id class BookAuthorOrderedId and add the composed primary key:

```
@RooToString
@RooEquals
@RooIdentifier
public final class BookAuthorOrderedId {
   @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Book book;

   @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="author_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Author author;
}
```

now comes the part where i have a bad feeling, because it looks like a workaround to me. in the book entity i pushed in the getter method for authors and replaced it with the query of the join table:

```
   public List<Author> getAuthors()
    {

        // return Author.findAllAuthorsOfBook(this);


        System.out.println("getAuthors()");
        EntityManager em = new Book().entityManager;
        TypedQuery<Author> q = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Author AS o WHERE o.id IN ( SELECT OA.id.author FROM eu.books2ebooks.roomanova.domain.BookAuthorOrdered OA where OA.id.book = :book ) ", Author.class);
        q.setParameter("book", this);
        List<Author> authorList = q.getResultList(); 
        //this.setAuthors(authorList);
        return authorList;
    }
```

and a method to get the bean value directly for fresh added authors:

```
public List<Author> getAddedAuthors() {
    return this.authors;
}
```

then i had to manipulate the book controller to call a self written method to insert/update the join table (at create/update/..):

```
public static void setOrderedBookAuthors(Book book, List<Author> authors) {
    // delete all associated authors of book:
    List<BookAuthorOrdered> bookAuthorOrdereds = BookAuthorOrdered.findAllBookAuthorOrdersOfBook(book);
    for (BookAuthorOrdered bookAuthorOrdered : bookAuthorOrdereds) {
        log.info("removing book author: " + printAuthor(bookAuthorOrdered.getId().getAuthor()));
        bookAuthorOrdered.remove();
    }
    if ( authors == null )
    {
        log.info("ordered authors: null. nothing to insert.");
        return;
    }
    log.info("inserting sorted authors: ");
    Integer authorSequence = 1;
    for (Author author : authors) {
        log.info("inserting book author sorted: " + printAuthor(author) + " as no " + authorSequence);
        BookAuthorOrdered bookAuthorOrdered = new BookAuthorOrdered();
        bookAuthorOrdered.setAuthorSequence(authorSequence);
        BookAuthorOrderedId id = new BookAuthorOrderedId(book, author);
        bookAuthorOrdered.setId(id);
        log.info("book author ordered: " + bookAuthorOrdered);
        bookAuthorOrdered.persist();

        authorSequence++;
    }
}
```

so far that works but it have the feeling that there must be a much more elegant way...